# Geokit-rails fresh setup, Could not find table 'locations' Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, geokit

I followed the [directions here](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails/blob/master/README.markdown) but when I run Location.all, I get

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'locations'
```

Are there any extra setup steps or configuration required for using geokit-rails in a Rails 5 app?  Does it have anything to do with the fact I'm still using Sqlite and haven't switched databases yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'locations'

The documentation refers to an **example** of how to setup [*geokit-rails*](https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails/blob/master/README.markdown) in the model. The gem ***doesn't serve/ship with a ready-made table***. You should generate the table instead. Assuming you already have `Location` model in your app, then generate a migration to create `locations` table

```
rails g migration create_locations
```

and do `rake db:migrate`